# Regular expression to match string containing both "dodo" and "#rules" in any order

Tags: python

I want to create a regular expression to match a string containing both "dodo" and "#rules" in any order.
this expression work for this order:

```
import re

pattern = '(^[A-Za-z]{4}) | ^#?([ a-zA-Z]{6})'

mystring = 'Dodo #rules'

result = re.match(pattern, mystring)

if result:

    print("Match successful.")

else:

    print("Match unsuccessful."))
```

Comment: use regex101.com for troubleshooting

Comment: `'dodo|#rules'` ?

Comment: @RaySteam yes in both order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match in any order:

```
pattern = (?:[A-Za-z]{4})|(?:#[a-zA-Z]{5})
```